# Removing duplicates from CSV -- performance problems

Tags: performance, crystal-lang

I have a CSV file which might look like this:

```
foo,bar,glib
"a","1","A"
"b","1","B"
"a","2","C"
"b","1","D"
```

I'm looping through that CSV file and want to remove any duplicate rows where `foo` and `bar` are the same, i.e. my resulting file should look like this:

```
foo,bar,glib
"a","1","A"
"b","1","B"
"a","2","C"
```

This is how I'm doing it:

```rb
require "csv"

File.open("input.csv") do |infile|
  reader = CSV.new(infile, header=true)
  File.open("output.csv", "w") do |outfile|
    printed_tuples = Array(Tuple(String, String)).new
    CSV.build(outfile) do |writer|
      while reader.next
        next if printed_tuples.includes?({reader.row["foo"], reader.row["bar"]})
        printed_tuples << {reader.row["foo"], reader.row["bar"]}
        writer.row reader.row.to_a
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The real CSV file is a lot bigger (386280 lines and 17 columns) and this gets so slow to the point that it's practically unusable.

Ironically I'm rewriting a python script because I had hoped for better performance, but for now the python version is much quicker.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to speed it up?

Comment: Do it in a unix shell using `sort` and `uniq`.

Comment: @RickJames This example is greatly simplified, in reality there is some column value remapping/manipulating going on before I'm filtering duplicates so I'd like it to be all in one piece

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The critical operation is searching for existing values. `Array#includes?` is pretty inefficient in this case: it needs to iterate through all previous rows (for duplicate rows, it's not all but typically half of them). Do that for each row, that's `O(N²)`.

You need a different data structure which can be searched faster. Crystal has a [`Set`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.30.0/Set.html) type, which is backed by a hash table.

There are probably even better data structures and algorithms for this problem, but `Set` is available in Crystal's standard library and should already improve things a lot.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot :-). If anyone's aware of some data structure that's even faster please do let me know.